# How to configure MariaDB to accept any username/password combination?

Tags: mariadb

I have MariaDB running on my development workstation. The service is bound to localhost and cannot be remotely accessed. I would like to adjust MariaDB so all username and password combinations get an instant root level access to MariaDB. I work with a lot of different codebases that all have their own "default" username/password combo and it'd save a lot of time if MariaDB just accepted all combos and essentially disabled auth. Is it possible to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a mysqld option `--skip-grant-tables` that can do this. On the down side if codebases try to create users/grants those SQL statements may fail.